# Eliminating internal collecting when constructing a Source as a response to data

Tags: scala, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I have a Flow (createDataPointFlow) which is constructed by performing a `mapAsync` which collects data points (via `Sink.seq`) which I would otherwise like to stream directly (i.e. without collecting first).

However, it is not obvious to me how I can do this without collecting items, it seems I need some sort of mechanism to publish my items directly to the output portion of the flow I am creating, but I'm new to this and don't know how to do that without getting explicit actors involved, which I would like to avoid.

**How can I achieve this without the need to collect things to a Sink first?** Remember what I want to achieve is full streaming without the explicit buffering that `Sink.seq(...)` is doing.

```scala
object MyProcess {

  def createDataSource(job:Job, dao:DataService):Source[JobDataPoint,NotUsed] = {
    // Imagine the below call is equivalent to streaming a parameterized query using Slick
    val publisher: Publisher[JobDataPoint] = dao.streamData(Criteria(job.name, job.data))
    // Convert to a Source
    val src: Source[JobDataPoint, NotUsed] = Source.fromPublisher(publisher)
    src
  }

  def createDataPointFlow(dao:DataService, parallelism:Int=1): Flow[Job,JobDataPoint, NotUsed] =
    Flow[Job].mapAsync(parallelism)(job =>
      createDataSource(job,dao).toMat(Sink.seq)(Keep.right).run()
    ).mapConcat(identity)

  def apply(src:Source[Job,NotUsed], dao:DataService,parallelism:Int=5) = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(){ implicit builder =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    //Source
    val jobs:Outlet[Job] = builder.add(src).out
    //val bcastJobsSrc: Source[Job, NotUsed] = src.toMat(BroadcastHub.sink(256))(Keep.right).run()
    //val bcastOutlet:Outlet[Job] = builder.add(bcastJobsSrc).out

    //Flows
    val bcastJobs:UniformFanOutShape[Job,Job] = builder.add(Broadcast[Job](4))
    val rptMaker = builder.add(MyProcessors.flow(dao,parallelism))
    val dpFlow = createDataPointFlow(dao,parallelism)

    //Sinks
    val jobPrinter:Inlet[Job] = builder.add(Sink.foreach[Job](job=>println(s"[MyGraph] Received job: ${job.name} => $job"))).in
    val jobList:Inlet[Job] = builder.add(Sink.fold(List.empty[Job])((list,job:Job)=>job::list)).in
    val reporter: Inlet[ReportTable] = builder.add(Sink.foreach[ReportTable](r=>println(s"[Report]: $r"))).in

    val dpSink: Inlet[JobDataPoint] = builder.add(Sink.foreach[JobDataPoint](dp=>println(s"[DataPoint]: $dp"))).in

    jobs ~> bcastJobs

    bcastJobs ~> jobPrinter
    bcastJobs ~> jobList
    bcastJobs ~> rptMaker ~> reporter
    bcastJobs ~> dpFlow ~> dpSink
    ClosedShape
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after re-reading the documentation about the various stages available it turns out that what I needed was a `flatMapConcat`:

```
def createDataPointFlow(dao:DataService, parallelism:Int=1): Flow[Job,JobDataPoint, NotUsed] =
    Flow[Job].flatMapConcat(createDataSource(_,dao))
```